# unable to install collectd on Rhel 7

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, repository

Requirement to install collectd to monitor resources.
Steps done do far:

```
    yum install epel-release # this failed as pubilc key is not installed

     yum install --nogpgcheck epel-release # failed with error 

Transaction check error:      

    file /etc/rpm/macros.ghc-srpm from install of epel-release-6-8.noarch conflicts with file from package redhat-rpm-config-9.1.0-72.el7.noarch

    yum install --nogpgcheck --skip-broken collectd # failed with error

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    collectd-4.10.9-4.el6.x86_64 from epel

Error: Package: collectd-4.10.9-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: collectd-4.10.9-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

The question: 
I have installed the epel repo
Is there another repo I should be using because of the conflicts error?

Answer (score 4):

> unable to install collectd on Rhel 7

```
$ rpm -qa epel-release
epel-release-7-11.noarch
```

... So please install the right version of epel-release. You got the EL6 version, epel-release-6-8.noarch ... ( and the wrong collectd : collectd-4.10.9-4.**el6**.x86_64 ).

`epel-release` https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm

Download, and install :
`# cd Downloads/ && yum install ./epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm`

`# yum install collectd` : I got version **5.8.0-1.el7**

Comment: Thank you. I found that indeed I has version 6 listed in the epel.repo file. Ones this was changed to 7 and then yum clean all, the new public key downloaded and I could then install collectd-5.8.0-1.el7

Comment: FYI you can just do `yum install https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm`